# Center text vertically (TextBlock)

Tags: xaml, uwp

I'm struggling to vertically center text using TextBlock. I know that it adds extra space above the space in case you use accents **but why it isn't consistent with the space below then**? There's a few extra pixels.

[image: bad vertically center image]

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,40,0,0" Background="#FF191919" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFBF0077">
    <Grid Width="41" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" BorderBrush="#FFBF0077">
        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockLocalScore" Text="0" FontFamily="Courier New" Foreground="#FF007AFF" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid Padding="4,8" BorderThickness="8,0" Width="104">
        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockMinutesLeft" Text="00" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="36" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontWeight="Light" TextAlignment="Center" Height="27" TextLineBounds="Tight" Margin="0,0,4,0" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockSecondsLeft" Text="30" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="36" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontWeight="Light" OpticalMarginAlignment="TrimSideBearings" TextAlignment="Center" Height="27" TextLineBounds="Tight" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid Width="41" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Padding="0,8" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" BorderBrush="#FFBF0077">
        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockRemoteScore"  Text="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="36" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontWeight="Light" OpticalMarginAlignment="TrimSideBearings" TextAlignment="Center" Height="27" TextLineBounds="Tight" Foreground="#FFFF3B30" />
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

I've played with Line Height and Text Line Bounds but I can't why a way to make the text still vertical centered once I change the font.

Updated code to reproduce issue:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,100,0,0" Background="#FF191919" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFBF0077">
    <Grid Width="51" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" BorderBrush="#FFBF0077">
        <TextBlock Text="0" FontFamily="Courier New" FontSize="36" Foreground="#FF007AFF" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
    <StackPanel Padding="4" BorderThickness="8,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="01" FontFamily="Courier New" FontSize="36" TextAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,4,0" />
        <TextBlock Text="11" FontFamily="Courier New" FontSize="36" TextAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid Width="51" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Padding="0,8" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" BorderBrush="#FFBF0077">
        <TextBlock Text="0" FontFamily="Courier New" FontSize="36" Foreground="#FF007AFF" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason the first FontFamily / FontSize / FontWeight need be different than the others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a play with these two properties. In your case you are probably more interested in [`TextLineBounds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.textlinebounds).

```
<TextBlock Text="80" FontSize="40" TextLineBounds="Tight" OpticalMarginAlignment="TrimSideBearings" />
```

---

### Update

I am not sure if your screenshot is 100% accurate. I have used your code to produce the following pictures. Note I have scaled them up by 10 times.

```
<Grid Width="41" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" BorderBrush="#FFBF0077">
    <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockLocalScore" TextLineBounds="Full" Text="80" FontFamily="Courier New" FontSize="36" Foreground="#FF007AFF" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <Rectangle UseLayoutRounding="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Fill="White" Height="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1" Margin="-21,0,0,0" />
    <Rectangle UseLayoutRounding="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Fill="White" Height="10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="1" Margin="-21,0,0,0" />
</Grid>
```

**With `TextLineBounds` set to `Tight`**

[image]

**With `TextLineBounds` set to `Full`**

[image]

Yes, on the first one, there's still a tiny little gap (about `0.3` epx) between the bottom edge of number *8* and the `Line`, but this is mostly due to [layout rounding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_UseLayoutRounding) and [effective pixel snapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/design-and-ui-intro). I don't think it's noticeable to human eyes. :)

*P.S. You cannot purely rely on checking the visuals from Blend Designer as sometimes the artboard doesn't get updated on time to give you the correct result. You should always run your app and check from there.*

Comment: That will render it on the top left but if VerticalAlignment is used and set to center this is what happens due to the extra space at the bottom http://imgur.com/l04qFTe

Comment: I also used your example and tried to set the line height equal to the parent's height and then used LineStackingStrategy and set it to "BlockLineHeight" and something similar but worse happens, this would work on CSS :/

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I saw the gap that happens when using Tight and couldn't find a way to fix it and thought that maybe I was doing something wrong.

Comment: Yeah I have been using it whenever I need something to be absolutely centered. It's not 100% accurate but it's hardly noticeable. Before they introduced this I had to manually change the margins and it was not fun. :P

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code and reproduced this behavior. If your have not set the height and width of `TextBlock`, it will set them based on your text font size automatically .
For example, If the `FontFamily` is `Courier New` and the font size is 25, and the actual width and height of `TextBlock` is 16.00244140625 , 29.3203125. It will generate deviation when you center the text vertically. However, you could manual correct it via modifying the Padding just like the follow

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried setting the height and width to only fit my character size but do to the additional space added you will have to play with the margin using values lower than zero (0.2) to compensate the margin that the character has at one of his sides (I think it was the right side) plus the one additional margin from the bottom that isn't consistent with the one from the top used for accents. I'll try to positionate it using padding though but as Justin XL pointed out, even when using TextLineBounds and setting it to tight it isn't 100% vertically centered.